# Rspec: Allure command line tool

Tags: ruby, rspec, allure

After installing `allure-rspec gem` and adding `require 'allure-rspec'` in `spec_helper.rb` file. I am able to generate results in `.xml` format.

Now I want to convert this `.xml` to actual `html` report for this [tutorial](http://allure.qatools.ru/) navigates us to here https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cli

I don't understand how this would help in generating `html` reports.

I am using this line to generate `.xml` in results directory

`bundle exec rspec spec/create_post/post_creation_spec.rb`

Answer (score 0):

1. From that `github` link clone(download zip) the `allure-ci` repo in your local machine.
2. Then go to project and create a directory a root level `directory-with-results`
3. copy the `.xml` you have in this directory.
4. Open terminal at root directory of this maven project
5. And run these commands one by one

   `allure generate directory-with-results`

   `allure report open`

if `JAVA_HOME` `maven_home` is configured properly,you will see the report generated in your default browser.